# alt+tab on physical keyboard not working anymore

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, emui, huawei-p20

on my P20Pro Android 9.0.0.159, something happened with my Logitech K380 BT keyboard ; suddenly the alt-tab combination stopped working.

I tried with another keyboard, same problem. The direct button "recent apps" stopped working too, it only does a *tab* now.

The other combinations and shortcuts work, just not this one.

I used the Android key test app and pressing alt-tab shows keycode 57 with KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT on.

Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: Keycode 57 is alt modifier i.e. alt key on the left side of the keyboard. The tab key is what's not registering. The tab key's constant value is 61.

Comment: Thx... so what can I do ?

Comment: What I believe is happening is the the specific key character map for your k380 keyboard is either not present or it has errors in the format either or the system is defaulting to the generic kcm (key character map) file. So one needs to be created for your specific vendor, device model, and desired layout. The thing is the file is a system file and the commands to get the needed information require escalated privileges. So to start, is your device rooted?

Comment: Not rooted, and if it's useful, alt tab didn't work with another keyboard either